# What is semi analytical solution?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am searching for the definition of a semi analytical solution.

I can't seem to find anything online, any help?

Comment: I goggled it and became many results. Here is the first google hit: "To overcome these issues, Carr and Turner [2] recently developed a semi-analytical solution approach for multilayer diffusion based on the Laplace transform and an appropriately-defined orthogonal eigenfunction expansion." See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.09925.pdf).

Comment: I am not saying it isn't common, I am saying I can't find a proper definition and I looked at that paper without being able to find a proper definition.

Comment: A lot of terms without proper definition. Same with "semi-empirical"

Comment: In addition to the answer by @Robert Israel, in complex analysis there is a notion of an *analytic function*. But this needs to be handled with care, and sometimes is or isnt relevant for the usage of the word "analytical" that is asked about here. These things are usually on a case by case basis..  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Analytical" and "semi-analytical" are not really technical terms, I think.  Roughly
speaking, "analytical" means "closed-form", i.e. expressed as a finite expression using
"well-known" functions.  What exactly is a "well-known" function may be debated: $\sin$ and $\cos$ certainly qualify, $\text{LambertW}$ and generalized hypergeometrics maybe not.
 As stated in the second page of the Carr and March article cited, the expression
in this case is only "semi-analytical" because it involves non-analytical  Laplace transforms of analytical functions.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, my current understanding of these words are:

**Closed form / analytical solution:** you can plug in the numbers and get the result directly.

**semi-closed form / analytical solution:** there is a numerical step involved, which is usually an integral or another operator that is computable efficiently and accurately.

These terms are mostly used in financial papers where we aim for the former types of solutions (for example Black-Scholes equation is an instance of it) but we usually end up with the latter for more complex models (for example pricing under Heston).